# Can´t change value when unchecked a radioButton

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have this input which is a radio button(example2) and I have others radio buttons with different purposes.

```
       <input name="example2" id="sent" type="radio" value="3">
       <input name="example2a" id="sent2a" type="radio" value=" ORDER BY date_hour DESC   ">
```

I have this code for check and uncheck my radio buttons.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ){

$.fn.uncheckableRadio = function() {

  return this.each(function() {
   $(this).mousedown(function() {
      $(this).data('wasChecked', this.checked);
  });
  $(this).click(function() {
      if ($(this).data('wasChecked'))
          this.checked = false;
      });
  });
};
})( jQuery );
$('input[type=radio]').uncheckableRadio();

</script>
```

And now the code for checking my radio button or uncheck:

```
$('#sent').change(function(){
    if( $('#sent').prop("checked")){
      status=3;
    } else {
      status=2;
}
```

I can change the status when I check the radio button but i can´t change the status when I uncheck the radio button.

What I'm looking for is if the radio button is checked i want status = 3 and if radio button is unchecked status = 2.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Both your radio buttons have the same `id="send"`. How will it work then ?

Comment: If I change the id the result is the same

Comment: Yes, thats because you have code only for `$('#sent').change` and not the other. Let me give you the code soon

Comment: Forget the second input, I just want uncheck the first input and change the "status = 2" and I just can´t do it

Comment: Provided the answer below in that case. using `$(this).is(':checked')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `change` you can use `click`
Try with this snippet example

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

  // uncheckableRadio
  (function( $ ){
  $.fn.uncheckableRadio = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
     $(this).mousedown(function() {
     $(this).data('wasChecked', this.checked);
    });
    $(this).click(function() {
     if ($(this).data('wasChecked'))
      this.checked = false;
     });
    });
  };
  })( jQuery );
  $('input[type=radio]').uncheckableRadio();

  // Radio click
  $('#sent, #sent2a').click(function(){
   if( $(this).prop("checked")){
     status=3;
   } else {
     status=2;
   }
   $("#status_span").html(status)
  });

 })
 </script>
</head>
<body>
A - <input name="example2" id="sent" type="radio" value="3"><br/>
B - <input name="example2a" id="sent2a" type="radio" value=" ORDER BY date_hour DESC   "><br/>
<div>status - <span id="status_span"></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input:radio[id^="sent"]').on('change', function(){'Your code here'});
```

Comment: The resulst is the same

Comment: My fault you have to select radio who starts with "sent" and not ending
$('input:radio[id^="sent"]').on('change', function(){'Your code here'});
I changed my origin comment

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$('#sent').bind('click', function() {
  //if un-checked
  if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    status=2;
  } else {
    //if checked
    status=3;
  }
});
```

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: It seems to be work here. I updated the answer swapping the status numbers. Maybe you can check now